# gwt images external to WAR file

Tags: gwt, web

I am working with GWT and I have some issues with the images. I need images outside my WAR file and, In order to make them visible in the application, I must put them inside the "target" folder ( I am using maven as well). The problem is that the target folder by definition is deleted every time recompile the project. This issue happens only in hosted mode, because when I deploy the application on Tomcat I can just change the server.xml adding the following statement

and it should read correctly images outside my WAR file(not tried yet due to another problem I have)

Can anybody give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What is the directory structure of your maven project? Why is there a requirement for you to put the images in the `target` folder? Typically in a Maven project the items you put in the src/main/resources/static such as images end up in the built artifact.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. It is not a requirement for me to use the target folder, it is only a workaround. The reason why i need external images is because my website is a social network(similar to facebook) so i cannot think of putting all the images of my users in the application war. For your information the structure is: Project(parent project, maven); ProjectGwt(it is the client and is developed wit GWT); ProjectCore(It contains the business logic, DAOs and so on and it is a dependency of the ClientProject)